# Запрос к базе данных и запись данных с условием

Tags: python, sqlite3

У меня есть цикл for, в котором находится запрос в базу данных. Как я могу сделать что бы, данные в таблицу mails не записывались если id там есть и он точно такой же? В наличии имеется такой код

```
            cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM mails")
            
          
            cursor.execute(""" INSERT INTO mails VALUES (?,?,?,?) """, (id, add, subject, date_mail))
            data_base.commit()
```

Comment: Смотреть в сторону того, что в sqlite есть конструкция "insert or ignore into" сделать на таблице соответствующий первичный/уникальный ключ что бы конструкция работала

Comment: Это мне нужно id получается сделать уникальным?

Comment: Да, если вы не хотите что бы в таблице были записи с одинаковым id, то он должен быть объявлен уникальным

Comment: В вы можете привести пример как она эта конструкция будет выглядеть , на примере моего примера кода что выше, с учетом того что id колонка уникальная?

Comment: после слова insert добавляете or ingone остальное не меняется. ну и select делать не обязательно